# Java pattern for subsequent Input & OutputStream

Tags: java, sockets, io, inputstream, outputstream

Hello stack overflow world, I've been struggling with the most straight forward and common problem within Java IO, for some time, and now need your help to tackle it.

Check out this piece of code I have in a try block, within a thread.run():

```
                // connect to client socket, and setup own server socket
                clientSocket = new Socket(serverHostname, CLIENT_PORT);

                //send a test command to download a file
                String downloadFileName = "sample.txt";
                DataOutputStream dataOutputStream = new DataOutputStream(clientSocket.getOutputStream());
                System.out.println("Sending a request to download file : " + downloadFileName + " from user: Arsa node"); //todo: replace with node user later
                dataOutputStream.writeUTF("D/sample.txt");

                //close socket if host isn't detected anymore, and if socket doesn't become null suddenly
                dataOutputStream.flush();
                dataOutputStream.close();
                System.out.println("****File has been sent****");

                in = new DataInputStream(clientSocket.getInputStream());
                byte[] retrievedFileData = new byte[8036];


                if (in.readInt() > 0) {
                    System.out.println("Starting file download!");
                    in.read(retrievedFileData);
                    System.out.println("File data has been read, converting to file now");

                //closing input stream will close socket also
                    in.close();
                }

                clientSocket.close();
```

2 Main questions that have been confusing me to death:

- Why does dataOutputStream.close() need to be run for writeUTF to actually send my string to the server socket, I find that when I don't have dos.close(), data isn't retrieved on the other side, further because I close it, I no longer can read from the socket - as it seems the socket connection becomes closed when the Output Stream is previously closed...

  - What's a better way, following some sort of pattern to do this? For context, all I'm trying to do is write the filename I'm looking to download to my client, then read the response right away, which I expect to be bytes with the file, any error handling I will consider as a part of my development.

Overall, it shouldn't be complicated to write something to a socket, then read and ingest it's response...which doesn't seem to be the case here,
any help would be greatly appreciated! If the ServerSocket code snippet is needed I'm happy to share.

Answer (score 0):

The observed behavior is just a side-effect of `close()`, as it calls `flush()` before closing to make sure any buffered data is sent. To solve your problem, you need to call the `flush()` method instead of closing.

This behavior is not unique to `DataOutputStream`: a lot of other `OutputStream` (or `Writer`) implementations apply buffering, and you will need to flush when you want to ensure the data is sent to the client, written to disk or otherwise processed.

BTW: The `DataOutputStream` and `DataInputStream` is for a very specific type of data serialization protocol that is particular to Java. You may want to consider carefully if this is the right protocol to use.

Comment: Appreciate the swift response, will consider a better stream decorator, however flush() alone doesn't seem to push my data across, until i get to my socket.close() then writeUTF seems to be successful. Why is that? Why isn't my data/filename being pushed to the server socket with just flush?

Does this mean I have to create a new socket connection for every subsequent type of input or output, seeming as I can't subsequently read after closing the output stream...

Comment: @ArsalanKhalid It should be, but sockets can apply yet another level of buffering that depending on the NO_NAGLE setting may wait a few seconds before actually sending the data if the sockets buffer is not full.

Comment: That still doesn't work! I'm finding data isn't read in the ServerSocket, until I my Client socket closes:                     clientSocket.close();, even with use of Thread.sleep()...

Comment: Have you tried `setTcpNoDelay(true)` on your client socket?

Comment: Yes, and sadly still no luck. I'm forced to be concluded with that you need a separate socket connection to read from a socket after you've already written to one. Am I crazy? IO can't be that bad...

Comment: Honestly, what you need here is to not roll your own. There are many very competent web service libraries that will take care of all this for you.

Comment: And I would love for that... what are examples of what you're talking about? I have webservices setup for the other tasks I'm doing, in this case I need a socket connection between nodes to send bytes, or files. I know WebSockets are an option, but that meant for lots of piping and config on top of existing Spring stack

Comment: @ArsalanKhalid: How do you know the data isn't being pushed? Maybe the bug is in your server.

Comment: Use, for example, Apache CXF and send the bytes as the body of a request or response.

Comment: @ArsalanKhalid Maybe you should show your server code as well.